# Expresso Store: Shipping Name - Surname goes missing

Tags: expresso-store, upgrade, tags

I've recently updated my installation of Store to 2.3.1. All seemed to be going smoothly, but my client has recently reported that surnames are going missing from peoples orders.

I'll break it down below:

The shipping name is captured as `{field:shipping_name} {error:shipping_name}`

Any name captured here is displayed correctly in the order admin screen:
[image: Order Interface]

However, when trying to show this name in the confirmation email only the first name is displayed. The template code is: `{shipping_name}`

Checking the member record the surname isn't being added to that either:
[image: Member record]

Have I missed some template changes? Do I need to capture first and surname separately now?

Any advice much appreciated.

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this in my situation by swapping the combined field

```
{field:shipping_name} {error:shipping_name}
```

for the separate first name and surname fields

```
{field:shipping_first_name} {error:shipping_first_name}
{field:shipping_last_name} {error:shipping_last_name}
```

though this is a workaround, not a fix.